# Why in react.js doesn't show the img

Tags: reactjs, image

How I can show the img on this component? In theory its sending the img address of each logo but is not working. What can I do

```
import React from "react";
import "../Style/JobListing.css";
import datas from "../data.json";

function JobListing() {
  const jobs = datas.map((data) => (
    <div className="JobListing" key={data.id}>
      <div className="topJL">
        <img src={data.logo} alt={data.company} />
      </div>
      <div className="middleJL">
        <div className="mTopSection">
          <div className="titleJL">
            <h3>{data.company}</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            {" "}
            {data.new ? (
              <div className="newJL">
                <span>NEW</span>
              </div>
            ) : null}
          </div>
          <div>
            {data.featured ? (
              <div className="featuredJL">
                <span>FEATURED</span>
              </div>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="mMidSection">
          <h2>{data.position}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="mBottonSection">
          <div className="bottonInfo">
            <p>{data.postedAt}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="bottonInfo">
            <p>{data.contract}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="bottonInfo">
            <p>{data.location}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="bottonJL">
        <div className="bottonTags">
          <div className="roleJL">{data.role}</div>
          <div className="levelJL">{data.level}</div>
          <div className="languagesJL">
            {data.languages.map((language, index) => (
              <div key={index} className="languageJL">
                {language}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="toolsJL">
            {data.tools.map((tool, index) => (
              <div key={index} className="toolJL">
                {tool}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ));
  return <React.Fragment>{jobs}</React.Fragment>;
}
export { JobListing };
```

this is one object of the data file

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "company": "Photosnap",
    "logo": "./assets/photosnap.svg",
    "new": true,
    "featured": true,
    "position": "Senior Frontend Developer",
    "role": "Frontend",
    "level": "Senior",
    "postedAt": "1d ago",
    "contract": "Full Time",
    "location": "USA Only",
    "languages": ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"],
    "tools": []
  }
```

I know how to solved if the object was on the component for example:

```
import React from "react";
import '../style/MiniNews.css'
import img1 from '../assets/image-retro-pcs.jpg'
import img2 from '../assets/image-top-laptops.jpg'
import img3 from '../assets/image-gaming-growth.jpg' 
const mininews=[
    {   
        img: img1,
        number:'01',
        title:'Reviving Retro PCs',
        p: 'What happens when old PCs are given modern upgrades'
    },
    {   
        img: img2,
        number: '02',
        title: 'Top 10 Laptops of 2022',
        p: ' Our best picks for varous needs and budgets'
    },
    {   
        img: img3,
        number: '03',
        title: 'The Growth of Gaming',
        p: 'How the pandemic has sparked fresh opportunities'
    }
]
function MiniNews(){
    const mininewslist= mininews.map(mininew=>
        <div className="MiniNews" key={mininew.number}>
            <div className="MiniNewsImg"><img src={mininew.img} alt='img News'/></div>
            <div className="MiniNewsInfo">
                <span>{mininew.number}</span>
                <h5>{mininew.title}</h5>
                <p>{mininew.p}</p>

            </div>

        </div>
        )
    return(
        <React.Fragment>{mininewslist}</React.Fragment>
    )
}

export {MiniNews}
```

But in this way I dont know how to do it, even chatgpt says that its fine

Comment: Add an additional `.` to the path to the image like the way it's imported in the other component. Does that solve it at all?

Comment: Is your assets folder located in your public folder? If so, you can import by setting "logo: /assets/photosnap.svg" for the first example. If not, you must use require to load the image: "../assets/image-retro-pcs.jpg" and "src={require(logo)}"

Comment: Go to the networking tab in devtools and find your image (you may have to reload for it to show up). Was the request successful? If not, what was the status code and/or error?